# How to replace a variable's comma-separated string with whitespaces?

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables, parameter-expansion

I have the following code at my docker-entrypoint script:

```
  if [[ -v SERVICE_NAMES ]]; then
    sudo sed -i -e "s#%SERVICE_NAMES%#$SERVICE_NAMES#g" /etc/someservice/someconfig.file
  else
    echo "SERVICE_NAMES variable not set, unable to write config without"
    exit 1
  fi
```

The content of the variable "SERVICE_NAMES" looks like this on container start:

```
hostname1,hostname2,hostname3
```

With my sed command I want to replace the SERVICE_NAMES variable with a placeholder within the someconfig.file, but separated using a whitespace not a comma, so that SERVICE_NAMES looks like this at my someconfig.file:

```
hostname1 hostname2 hostname3
```

Is it possible to replace the commas with whitespaces before I write to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `tr` to transliterate commas to spaces

The [`tr` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1p.html) can be used to transliterate a string (replace a character in a string with another character). The format is as follows:

```bash
tr <character> <replacement-character>
```

`tr` gets its input from stdin (file descriptor `0` or `/dev/stdin`) so we have to either create a [Bash pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html), use [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), or use a here-string.

```bash
# Pipeline
echo "$SERVICE_NAMES" | tr ',' ' '
# Input Redirection with Process Substitution
tr ',' ' ' <<(echo "$SERVICE_NAMES")
# Here-String
tr ',' ' ' <<<"$SERVICE_NAMES"
```

### Using Bash's parameter expansion for expanding commas to spaces

In Bash, [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) can be used to replace *all of the commas* with spaces. The syntax is as follows: `${parameter/pattern/string}`. However, you need to ensure that your pattern begins with another forward slash as per the man pages.

> If `pattern` begins with ‘/’, all matches of `pattern` are replaced with `string`. Normally only the first match is replaced.

```bash
echo "${SERVICE_NAMES//,/ }"
```

### More `sed` commands

The command [`sed` can execute multiple commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html) in succession by adding more `-e <command>` arguments or by separating the commands with a `;` (semicolon), however, any commands added will be applied to the whole file.

To avoid affecting the whole file, we can make a separate call to `sed` with `$SERVICE_NAMES` as the data to operate on. We can use [`sed`'s `y` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html) to do transliteration on `$SERVICE_NAMES`.

```bash
# Pipeline
echo "$SERVICE_NAMES" | sed -e 'y/,/ /'
# Input Redirection with Process Substitution
sed -e 'y/,/ /' <<$(echo "$SERVICE_NAMES")
# Here-String
sed -e 'y/,/ /' <<<"$SERVICE_NAMES"
```

### Utilizing other scripting languages

I won't provide examples for other scripting languages here since there are simply too many. In general, most scripting languages support string splitting, joining strings, regular expressions, string/character substitutions. Some examples of these languages are Python, JavaScript, AWK, and Perl.

For solving issues like this with scripts, you can take your data and either place it directly into the script that will be executed, get the data to standard input (pipelines, input redirection, or here-strings), or utilize command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use parameter expansion to replace every comma with a space during the variable expansion:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s#%SERVICE_NAMES%#${SERVICE_NAMES//,/ }#g" /etc/someservice/someconfig.file
```

This isn't any riskier than what you started with, since the replacement text doesn't have any additional `#` symbols; just keep in mind that if any of your hostnames end up with `#` symbols in them, the `sed` command will fail.